# JAVA two equal strings return false

Tags: java, string, swing, string-comparison

I have a JTable and i need to check if the JTable has an entry equal to one in my database ( It does ) . But when i check it out, it gives me false . Both result are the same ( Cat and Cat ).

```
ResultSet resultset;
try {
    // Query declaration, etc
    while(resultset.next()){
        String name = resultset.getString(1);
        int quantity = resultset.getInt(2);
        checkListQuantity(name, quantity);
        }   

public void checkListQuantity(String name, int quantity){
        String string = String.format("%-40s", name);
            for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
                System.out.println("Name :"+name);
                System.out.println("Column :"+ model.getValueAt(i, 1));
                System.out.println(name.equals(String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, 1))));
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: May be spaces at the start or end? trim() the String and see.

Comment: Yes. i tested it by adding a string after the value and it looks like my table value has a lot of space after . Why ?

Comment: How would we know? Where does the table come from? How was it entered? etc.

Comment: Nevermind .. It was just a mistake :/

Comment: A general remark: all the answers to this question should really be just comments, as done by @Nambari.

Comment: @ChthonicProject they are appropriate answers to the question as they solve the problem stated. The real issue is that this question is due to a minor typo/mistake.

Comment: Yes, that too. Agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try trimming your values:

```
 System.out.println(name.trim().equals(String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, 1).trim())));
```

Comment: That was the problem !

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
System.out.println("Name : #"+name+"#");
System.out.println("Column : #"+ model.getValueAt(i, 1)+"#");
System.out.println(name.equals(String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, 1))));
```

To see spaces

Comment: Thats what i used too . Thanks ! Worked